# Ruby on Rails - How to save current datetime to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

When a user created an account the current datetime has to be send to the database. I got a column with for example "a_started_at".

Controller:

```
def create
.......
   if @user.save
  @current_Time = DateTime.now
  @current_Time = current_time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
   end
.......
end
```

For the user params I sent it within the "company_attributes"

```
company_attributes[a_started_at => @current_Time]
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: How can I save the current DateTime to my database? This doesn't work for me..

Comment: are u seeing an error or is it running ok but just not doing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I just did `users.company.started_at = DateTime.now` in the create method and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take advantage of [`ActiveRecord::Timestamp`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html): If there is a column `created_at` in the database table, then Rails would automatically save the current time into that column when creating a new row.

To manually set a datetime column when a user signs up, you have two options depending on how explicit you want your `started_at` datetime field to be:

1) With a callback in your model:

```
# in models/user.rb
before_validate :set_started_at

private
  def set_started_at
    self.started_at ||= Time.current
  end
```

2) by providing more attributes when creating your User in the controller:

```
# in your controller:
@user = User.new(user_attributes.merge(started_at: Time.current))
if @user.save 
  # ...
```

Comment: Yes I got that too, but I need a second column with the exact same date when the user submit.

Comment: Why do you need two different columns with the exact same values?

Comment: Well we have a "started_at" and a "ended_at". I need it to calculate the subscription. And the value of "started_at" can change later when the user buys a new subscription.